# Can't change keyboard layout inside vncserver

Tags: xfce, keyboard-layout, vnc, tiger

How to change keyboard layout inside (tiger) vncserver? I am running `startxfce4` inside it. I can show country flag in the corner and switch layout by clicking on it, but I can't switch by keyboard shortcut, although I set it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change from the GUI, I recomended apply this command:

```
setxkbmap us
```

If in the case you prefer the *us* distribution. You can investigate more about it over [here](https://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/setxkbmap.1.xhtml)

Comment: I can change from GUI, but only by clicking national flag by mouse.